# Which Linux distro is best for me?

Tags: linux

I need to use Linux for Web Development, I also want to manage a Linux server. So which is the best option for me:

- Use one Linux distro for programming, and another for server.
- Use one Linux distro for both purposes, if so, which Linux distro is good for both purposes?

Anybody can give me some suggestions?

Comment: The choice of the distribution does not matter much. What matters much more is what you learn of it. You'll need to learn Unix principles and command language (the shell) - don't depend upon graphical interfaces for system administration, learn how to use the shell, standard utilities (like `gawk`, `sed`, `grep` etc...) and how to edit configuration files.

Comment: Downvoting.  I believe this falls under the 'questions not to ask' category: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can advice you to use debian (http://www.debian.org/) for both development and production environments but this is my own preference.

This is the classic question where everyone has their own opinion and nobody wins...

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) it's easy to use, you can use apt-get to install basically everything you need.